# Reset admin password in Cent OS 7 from grub

Tags: centos, boot, grub2, password

I just recently installed cent os 7 and I forgot the admin user password so now I couldnt log in and locked out.

I entered the grub boot menu and tried to change the password using password command but didnt work out.

Am I completely locked out? How to reset the admin password from grub?

Answer (score 1):

on your grub boot menu as its booting, there should be a list of available kernels.
will look like this:
[Grub menu](http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/image55.png)

while there, hit `e` to edit, select the `second line` and hit `e` again to edit it, add a `1` to the end of the line, press `esc` to save changes and `b` to boot.

This will force the system to boot into `single user` mode which will be a `root shell` you can then reset the password with `passwd` and `shutdown -r now` to reboot to normal mode.

The changes you made to the `grub window` are temporary, so you dont have to change them back.